# Cannot find CDI beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I created this simple CDI bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;


    @Named("DashboardController")
    @ViewScoped
    public class Dashboard implements Serializable
    {
    .......
    }
```

I removed all configuration from faces-config.xml. I created this beans.xml file into WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

When I opened the JSF page the bean cannot be found. Can you tell me what am I missing? I don't want to declare the beans into faces-config.xml.

P.S I don't know if this is important or not but this is a WAB package with CDI beans.

Comment: `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` from JSF doesn't mix with `javax.inject.Named` from CDI. You should use plain CDI or JSF managed bean, not both.

Comment: Have a look into ViewAccessScope from CODI as well if you plan on using CDI

Comment: in order to rule other error possibilities out, change the scope to SessionScoped and run again.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use ViewAccessScoped instead of ViewScoped.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;
//Note the different import
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;


    @Named("dashboardController")
    @ViewAccessScoped
    public class Dashboard implements Serializable
    {
    .......
    }
```

You should also start the name in Named with a non-capital letter.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know `ViewAccessScoped` is from the CODI framework not CDI.

Comment: OP is not using CODI, and you haven't even mentioned the framework in your answer. As far as any other onlooker to this question is concerned, it appears as if `ViewAccessScoped` is part of CDI

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the faces_config file to your `META-INF` folder of your WAB as described [in this thread](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/re-named-cdi-bean-wab-not-available-jsf-page)

That aside, even if the bean is found, you might still have problems with the scoping; You can't apply a JSF scope to a CDI bean.
CDI's `@ConversationScoped` is a somewhat less than convenient alternative to JSF's `@ViewScoped`. The inconvenience of the scope lies in the fact that you need to inject an extra managed object and you have to actively manage the scope yourself. To use:

1. Annotate your bean with `@ConversationScoped`

   ```
   @Named("DashboardController")
   @ConversationScoped
   public class Dashboard implements Serializable
    {

    }
   ```
2. Inject the `Conversation` object into your bean

   ```
   @Inject
   private Conversation conversation;
   ```
3. On this object, you need to call `begin()` and `end()` to start the "conversation" (a la viewscope) and "end" the conversation (like JSF does by destroying a viewscoped bean) respectively. This is a matter of design and context. At the very least, you can call `conversation.begin()` in a `@PostConstructor`. Where you end the conversation depends on your specific use case

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can I automatically free the resources using this code: `@Remove
public void finishIt(){
     conversation.end();
}`. I want to place it at the bottom of the managed bean and let the Application server to manage the resources alone when the user closes the page.

Comment: @PeterPenzov yes you can. In an EJB, that's the perfect place to place it

Comment: As @BalusC recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427217/ajax-pages-with-cdi-beans-and-conversationscoped The new JSF 2.2 will fix this problem. I just will switch to the new version.

Comment: @PeterPenzov that's fine. Don't think 2.2. has been officially released though.

Comment: link is broken my friend